# Drawing Quarter-Circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

I have drawn a square as shown below. However, I need to draw a quarter-circle inside the square such that the radius of the quarter-circle is 1 and it the center is drawn in the bottom left. Please keep code minimal, I am a beginner.

```
\coordinate[label=below:$A$] (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate[label=:$B$] (B) at (0,1);
    \coordinate[label=:$C$] (C) at (1,1);
    \coordinate[label=below:$D$] (D) at (1,0);
    \draw[] (0,0)--(0,1)--(1,1)--(1,0)--(0,0);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that with

```
\draw (D) arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=1];
```

This may or may not be self-explanatory. It draws a circular arc with radius 1 starting at the point D. `start angle=0` means that it is the point on the circle at an angle of zero that is placed at `D`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate[label=below:$A$] (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate[label=:$B$] (B) at (0,1);
  \coordinate[label=:$C$] (C) at (1,1);
  \coordinate[label=below:$D$] (D) at (1,0);

  \draw (A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--cycle;

  \draw (D) arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like the simple answers. Why there is a little sign in the image at the bottom right? A cropping problem?

Comment: @Sebastiano No, a screenshot problem. It is the mouse cursor that is included in the screenshot.

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much! I think I get it now--such a simple answer as well!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to the problem would be adding:

```
\draw[-] (1, 0) arc (0:90:1);
```

this will draw an arc from a circle of radius 1 from (1,0) to (0,1)